# How to create connection between azure storage account for file reading to AAS using azure function in powershell

Tags: powershell

```
$StorageKey=(Get-AzStorageAccountKey -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroup -Name $StorageName).Value[0]
```

I am using above mentioned parameters but I am getting the error message:

> ERROR: The specified module 'AzureAD' was not loaded because no valid
> module file was found in any module directory.Exception :Type :
> System.Management.Automation.RemoteExceptionSerializedRemoteException
> : System.IO.FileNotFoundException: The specified module 'AzureAD' was
> not loaded because no valid module file was found in any module

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: simple error msg getting

Comment: ERROR: The specified module 'AzureAD' was not loaded because no valid module file was found in any module directory.Exception             :Type                           : System.Management.Automation.RemoteExceptionSerializedRemoteException      : System.IO.FileNotFoundException: The specified module 'AzureAD' was not loaded because no valid module file was found in any module

Comment: Did you google the error? It's very common

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First make sure that the [Azure Az PowerShell Module is installed](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/install-az-ps?view=azps-7.1.0). e.g:

```
Install-Module -Name Az -Scope CurrentUser -Repository PSGallery -Force
```

Then to start working with Azure PowerShell, sign in with your Azure credentials. e.g.:

```
Connect-AzAccount
```

Then you should be able to work and execute the rest of your script.

Comment: that to i tried but not working

Comment: "not working" means nothing. Again, what error are you getting when you do this?

Comment: ERROR: 'this.Client.SubscriptionId' cannot be null.Exception             :Type       : Microsoft.Rest.ValidationExceptionRule       : cannot be nullTarget     : this.Client.SubscriptionIdTargetSite